# Configuring Qt Creator for GTK+

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, gtk, qt-creator

I can't setup Qt Creator for GTK+ on Ubuntu. I'm trying to compile this example but I got errors complaining about header files :

but I fixed them by adding this to the `.pro` file

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gtk-2.0 \
/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ \
/usr/include/cairo/ \
/usr/include/pango-1.0/ \
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/ \
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/ \
/usr/include/atk-1.0/
```

but I don't know what to add for the `LIBS +=`

Comment: Why use a KDE/Qt tool to develop Gnome/GTK+ applications?

Comment: I just prefer Qt Creator as an IDE and I must work GTK+ for a school project. Do you recommend an other IDE ?

Comment: All in all, I think I use vim probably about half of the time, alongside geany or some other light editor. For more complex GUI building, I use Glade

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Glade has many bugs, besides for coding Qt creator is the best

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It worked by adding

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += gtk+-2.0
```